# How to undo "assert" in python?

Tags: python, assert

In an early function, let's call it `a`, i have to make sure that the `a` function doesn't produce an answer that is too small (let's say, answer must be bigger than 10). 
But later on, in a second function `b` (which uses function `a` as one of its inputs), it is okay if the same answer that is being modified is smaller than the earlier `assert` statement.

Is there a way to do this?

When function `b` produced an answer that was too small, I tried to save how small the answer was in variable, but I'm still getting assert errors when I run doctest.

```
def grade_on_project(student_project_score, max_score, overall_score):
    project_grade = student_project_score / max_project_score
    assert project_grade > 0.6 # (student fails the class if any of their scores on a project are too low)
    overall_score +=student_project_score
    return overall_score

def who_fails_first(operation, person1, person2)
    if (operation(person1, max_score, person1) <= 150 and (operation(person2, max_score, overall_score) > 150:
        print(student 1 failed)
    if (operation(person2, max_score, overall_score) <= 150 and (operation(person1, max_score, overall_score) > 150:
        print(student 2 failed)

 who_fails_first(grade_on_project, 5, 9)
```

Comment: Could you post your code? Seeing the actual code is much better than reading a description of it.

Comment: `function a` describes a behavior that you expect for a given set of inputs.  That contract between input and expected behavior should be (and as you're finding, *needs* to be) independent of the context in which it's called.

Comment: okay, i posted it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assertions should **not** be used to implement logic of some piece of code. Why? Because you have no guarantee that they are actually raised!

```
$python -c 'assert False'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
$python -O -c 'assert False'   # doesn't raise an error!
$
```

<sup>`-O` option is for "optimizations". But it also remove all assertions</sup>

`assert`s should be used to *debug*, checking for conditions that should *never* happen in a well written program.

If you want to handle special inputs in some way you should use *exceptions*:

```
def grade_on_project(student_project_score, max_score, overall_score):
    project_grade = student_project_score / max_project_score

    if project_grade > 0.6:
        raise ValueError('Student fails if at least one project grade is too low.')

    overall_score +=student_project_score
    return overall_score
```

Or you might write a custom exception like:

```
class StudentFailed(ValueError):
    def __init__(self, message, grade):
        super(StudentFailed, self).__init__(message)
        self.grade = grade
```

And change the `if` to:

```
if project_grade > 0.6:
    raise StudentFailed('One project has grade too low.', project_grade)
```

Then when you catch the exception you can still access the grade that made it fail via the `grade` attribute of the exception.

If you don't want to raise the exception in a particular situation you could add a parameter, such as `low_grade_is_ok` and modify the function as:

```
def grade_on_project(student_project_score, max_score,
                     overall_score, low_grade_is_ok=False):
    project_grade = student_project_score / max_project_score

    if not low_grade_is_ok and project_grade > 0.6:
        raise ValueError('Student fails if at least one project grade is too low.')

    overall_score +=student_project_score
    return overall_score
```

Then in the function where you don't want to raise an exception you can call it with `low_grade_is_ok=True` and no exception will be raised in that case.